"The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type." Error React
Started working on a project last night, woke up to work on it today, and I'm randomly getting the error: "The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.". Nothing has changed since I last worked on this. I didn't even commit. No, nothing has changed to the audio files. I have exported them multiple times, in Audacity, FL, and used both .wav and .mp3. Same error. Seems to be completly random.
  const playSound = (url, volume) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => audioContext.current.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
      .then(audioBuffer => {
        const source = audioContext.current.createBufferSource();
        const gainNode = audioContext.current.createGain();
        gainNode.gain.value = volume;
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(gainNode).connect(audioContext.current.destination);
        source.start(0);
      });

My play sound function. All my audio clips are in one folder, /public/sounds/.
React decodeAudioData randomly stopped working.

does the data retrieved by the fetch look correct? Perhaps your server is sending something other than audio data

@JaromandaX ok.. added some debug and it not receiving a wav file. Its receiving text/html

so, what changed on the server?

@JaromandaX nothing

what is the content of the text/html - perhaps it's a clue
